# Stripe "invalid_request_error" - Card number not being passed from form to model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments, activemerchant

I'm integrating active merchant with Stripe into my rails app and when i check the Stripe log i see the following:

`type: "invalid_request_error"
 message: "You must supply either a card or a customer id"`

The card number is not being passed from the form in my view to the method in my model.

I must need to make an amendment in my controller to get this working but i'm not sure what.

MODEL

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :order_products
has_many :products, through: :order_products

attr_accessor :card_number, :security_code, :card_expires_on

def credit_card

    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        :number                 => card_number,
        :first_name             => first_name,
        :last_name              => last_name,
        :verification_value     => security_code,
        :month                  => card_expires_on{month},
        :year                   => card_expires_on{year}
        )
end

    def purchase(basket)

    response = GATEWAY.purchase(Product.total_basket_price(basket)*100, credit_card)

end
end
```

CONTROLLER

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

def create

    @order = Order.new

    basket.each do |item_id|
        @order.order_products.build(product: Product.find(item_id))
    end

    if @order.save!
        if @order.purchase(basket)
            render "show"
        else
            render "new"
        end
    else
        render "new"
    end



end
end
```

VIEW

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :card_number %>
  <%= f.input :security_code, label: "Security code (CVC)" %>
  <%= f.input :card_expires_on, as: :date, discard_day: true, add_month_numbers: true, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 10, order: [:month, :year], label: "Card expiration date"  %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Confirm and pay" %>

<% end %>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Many Thanks

Comment: What is your Rails version?

Comment: Hey @Kirti it's 4.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating the `order` object with values passed from the form which is why you receive the error.

**Notice:** `@order = Order.new` in `create` action. This would simply create an instance of `Order` model with no attributes set.

With Rails 4, you would need to whitelist the attributes (even the virtual attributes) which you would like to be saved.

So, update the `@order` instantiation in `create` action as below:

```
@order = Order.new(order_params)
```

And in the `order_params` method in your controller, make sure that you permit the attributes.

**UPDATE:**

Change your `order_params` as below:

```
def order_params
  if params[:order]["card_expires_on(1i)"] && params[:order]["card_expires_on(2i)"] && params[:order]["card_expires_on(3i)"]
    ## Set "card_expires_on" to a "Date" object created using the three values
    ## passed from the form "card_expires_on(1i)" and "card_expires_on(2i)", "card_expires_on(3i)" 
    params[:order][:card_expires_on] = Date.new(params[:order].delete("card_expires_on(1i)").to_i, params[:order].delete("card_expires_on(2i)").to_i , params[:order].delete("card_expires_on(3i)").to_i)
  end
  params.require(:order).permit(:card_number, :security_code, :card_expires_on )
end
```

Update `credit_card` method in `Order` model as shown below:

```
def credit_card
    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        :number                 => card_number,
        :first_name             => first_name,
        :last_name              => last_name,
        :verification_value     => security_code,
        :month                  => card_expires_on.month,  ## Get "month" from date object
        :year                   => card_expires_on.year    ## Get "year" from date object
        )
end
```

**Notice:**

`card_expires_on.month` and NOT `card_expires_on{month}`

**AND**

`card_expires_on.year` and NOT `card_expires_on{year}`

As you can see (highlighted) in the params generated upon form submission:

> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"ZWlCaOUPbignlnoULIMpfMCcD9NXQ2Czb0hcQyq9ad4=", 
>   "order"=>{"first_name"=>"",  "last_name"=>"",  "email"=>"", 
>   "address_1"=>"",  "address_2"=>"",  "city"=>"",  "postal_code"=>"", 
>   "country_code"=>"United Kingdom",  "card_number"=>"4242424242424242", 
>   "security_code"=>"123",  **"card_expires_on(3i)"=>"1", 
>   "card_expires_on(2i)"=>"5",  "card_expires_on(1i)"=>"2016"}**, 
>   "commit"=>"Confirm and pay"}

for the date field `card_expires_on`, you receive three different key's named

`card_expires_on(1i)` => which points to "year"

`card_expires_on(2i)` => which points to "month"

`card_expires_on(3i)` => which points to "date" by default set as 1 with a hidden field as you have not allowed it to input it

Comment: Hi @Kirti, so i tried whitelisting like that earlier and it didn't work for some reason. I now get an error with the `:card_expires_on` attribute which i was kind of expecting because as you can see in the Order model i've said this `:month  => card_expires_on{month}` and `:year  => card_expires_on{year}`. The railscast by Ryan Bates uses `card_expires_on.month` but this doesn't work for me. The error i get is `multiparameter assignment error`

Comment: Share the params hash generated upon form submission. So I can see how exactly you are passing `card_expires_on`.

Comment: `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ZWlCaOUPbignlnoULIMpfMCcD9NXQ2Czb0hcQyq9ad4=",
 "order"=>{"first_name"=>"",
 "last_name"=>"",
 "email"=>"",
 "address_1"=>"",
 "address_2"=>"",
 "city"=>"",
 "postal_code"=>"",
 "country_code"=>"United Kingdom",
 "card_number"=>"4242424242424242",
 "security_code"=>"123",
 "card_expires_on(3i)"=>"1",
 "card_expires_on(2i)"=>"5",
 "card_expires_on(1i)"=>"2016"},
 "commit"=>"Confirm and pay"}`

Comment: and this is the full error msg:  `1 error(s) on assignment of multiparameter attributes [error on assignment [1, 5, 2016] to card_expires_on (undefined method "klass" for nil:NilClass)]`

Comment: Ok. Got it. The `card_expires_on ` required little bit tweaking. Read the `UPDATE` section in my answer and follow it exactly and your issue should resolve.

Comment: Ok. I made the changes and now it gives me `undefined method "delete" for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Oops! There was a typo. All `:post` should `:order`. I have updated order_params code. Try now

Comment: Okay awesome! i should have noticed that too, thank you. Would you be so kind as to explain what was going on?? Maybe we could go to chat?

Comment: No Problem. Glad to help :) I will add notes about it later in the answer as I have to leave for meeting.

Comment: Hey @kirti, i'm about to log off for the night but if you get chance to add some explanatory notes that i can check in the morning i'd be very grateful! Thanks so much again

Comment: Added extra explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey @KirtiThorat thanks for the added explanation on my question yesterday. I think i'm still a bit stuck as to what this line is doing: params[:order][:card_expires_on] = Date.new(params[:order].delete("card_expires_on(1i)").to_i, params[:order].delete("card_expires_on(2i)").to_i , params[:order].delete("card_expires_on(3i)").to_i)
and why in the Railscast by Ryan Bates he didn't have to specifically set "card_expires_on" to a "Date" object?

Comment: Hey @Kirti are you there? sorry for the hassle, it would just really help

Comment: I saw the video of Ryan, its 5 years old, he is probably using Rails 2/ 3 in that video. I have never worked on Rails 3. I started on Rails 4. Rails 4 introduced strong parameters and this is how I have used it successfully in couple of my projects in case of `date`, `datetime` and `time` fields as they are passed as `multiparameter` arguments. For ex: card_expires_on(1i),card_expires_on(2i),.. May be you can post a comment on Ryan's episode about how it should be implemented in `Rails 4`. I helped you to resolve your query with my knowledge of `Rails 4`. That's all I can assist on this issue.